# How to do transparent background on few div to see background of parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#wrapper{
    height:500px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/f1uCUEJ.jpg');
}
#menu:before{
    width:500px;
    height:60px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#menu{
    position: fixed;
    top:60px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    height: 300px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#circle{
    position: fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: #000;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
#circle2{
    position: fixed;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}
#circle3{
    position: fixed;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    background: #000;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

#circle4{
    position: fixed;
    top: 54px;
    left: 54px;
}
.btn{
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    width:60px;
    height: 30px;    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#plus{
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
#minus{
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
```

And following HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="circle">
        <div id="circle2">
            <div id="circle3">
                <div id="circle4">
                    <button id="plus" class="btn">+</button>
                    <button id="minus" class="btn">-</button>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me to understand how I can achieve solution, which will make "transparent" black circles and I could see only image? If I make now this black color as - `background: rgba(0,0,0,0)`. I can see "menu" bars and I'd like to not see them.

There's following link with example: http://jsfiddle.net/88Uxw/122/

Comment: Im confused, what is it that you are trying to achieve? This: http://jsfiddle.net/88Uxw/123/ ??

Comment: Also wondering. Do you wish to just have your circle thing completely transparent?

Comment: I wish to have thic 2 black circle transparent and "see" background while left and top "menu" is still visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alvaro Menéndez I was able to do what I wanted to do. That's solution for my problem:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="shape"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap2">
        <div id="shape2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="shape3">
        <button id="plus" class="btn">+</button>
        <button id="minus" class="btn">-</button>                    
    </div>
    <div id="left-menu"></div>
    <div id="top-menu"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#shape {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#shape:before {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:15%; top:15%;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0px 0 250px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

#left-menu{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width: 59px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
}

#top-menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width: 300px;
    height: 59px;
}

#shape2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}

#shape2:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

#shape3{
    position: fixed;
    top: 69px;
    left: 69px;
}

.btn{
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width:120px;
    height: 60px;    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.btn:hover{
    background: #fff;
}

#plus{
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
}

#minus{
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
}
```

And working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L9aeu4o3/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/88Uxw/127/)**

Basically instead of using circles with background one inside the other, make the black color with border and set the "white" ones to not have any background:

```
#circle{
    position: fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
      border: 15px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#circle2{
    position: fixed;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}

#circle3{
    position: fixed;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    border-radius: 90px;
      border: 15px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

#circle4{
    position: fixed;
    top: 54px;
    left: 54px;
}

.btn{
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    width:60px;
    height: 30px;    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

Don't forget to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to keep the border inside you fixed size container.

Comment: You make it "right" however I wanted to not see that top and left bar when these circles are transparent

Comment: Thats' not just a bit more complex. That's really difficult to achieve and requires to work on it. Don't think you'll find many people willing to do the code for you. I would recomend You to search this web around (as a tip search for "transparency cutout") and once you are close and you have worked in your code, let us know what you have tried and We may see why it may not working.. Gl with your project